# Unity 3D: OpenFolderPanel is not working in Mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, explorer

I wanna select an image and upload that. Am using `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel` to open the explorer. It works in builder,but not working in Mobile device. Do this have any reason??
cheers..

Answer (score 0):

The name is `EditorUtility`, it resides in the `UnityEditor` namespace. `UnityEditor` classes are only available within the Unity Editor.

Comment: I've yet to see a mobile app that provides a "file open" dialog. Typically it's up to you to present the files in a way that's convenient to the user, for instance a list or table view of the files in a specific location or matching specific criteria.